# How to change merge mode for eclipse egit merge tool?

Tags: eclipse, git, egit, mergetool

We are working with Git and Eclipse. If I'm opening the merge tool to resolve a conflict I get this dialog:

[image]

I want to change this afer I marked *Don't ask again* before. But just cannot find the correct preference page.

Where can I change this after the dialog does not show up anymore?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change this in Eclipse Git preferences. Go to `Window` -> `Preferences` -> `Team` -> `Git` and there is dropdown for Merge `Merge tool content`.